# Trying to trace a dystopian short story about a man who can remember how good life used to be, in a world that’s forgotten what they have lost

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a sci-fi short that I read in the early 90s. It starts with a man walking up to somebody who’s trying to roll a cigarette using weeds, and starts telling him how good real cigarettes used to taste.

He upsets everyone he talks to because he makes them realise what they don’t have.

I’m looking for this story to help put together an article on the repudiation of history.

I’ve tried various google searches, but it keeps throwing out 'we can remember it for you wholesale' which isn’t right.

The irony that I might be the only person who can remember this story isn’t lost on me!

Comment: Not this but take a look at [Consider Her Ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consider_Her_Ways) and [The Futurological Congress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Futurological_Congress)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SciFi.SE, Please can you take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/39144) and [edit] in any more details you can remember?

Comment: I've read it as well but can't recall title/author. The old man is being smuggled around by an organisation who wants everyone to remember how good it all was in the old days. He describes the dashboard of some car (dodge viper?) and this petrolhead bursts into tears. They sit him down for a meal and he knows they're really spoiling him because he counts 27 peas on his plate.... I read this in an anthology and the story intro was something like "this man's crime against society is remembering how good life was"   I think the secret police were wanting to stop him spreading unrest

Comment: The cigarette thing reminds me of a Phillip K. Dick setting that he used for both a short story and a novel. Can you recall any other details?

Comment: Brilliant advice, David Tonhofer - thank you; I’ll check those out,

Comment: Danny McG - this is exactly right.  You’ve remembered a lot more than I did.  Now we just need the title!

Comment: For your article, you might like to check out a scene in 1984 by George Orwell, where Winston Smith meets an old man and asks him about life before the revolution.  See here, starting at paragraph 3 : https://www.gateoflove.com/1984-george-orwell/15/

Comment: Thank you,Pete.  This is already in my list - but you couldn’t know that; so I’m grateful for you pointing it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is Ray Bradbury's [*To the Chicago Abyss* (1963)](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64846) (Per DavidW comment, [full text available on Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v024n05_1963-05_PDF/page/n29/mode/1up) -- it's also part of [*The Best from Fantasy and Science Fiction: A Special 25th Anniversary Anthology* (1974)](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?35682), which is where I read it); going from memory:

- The protagonist (an old man) has a habit of talking to strangers and describing now-rare or gone things, acting with gestures, sound effects, and sense memory (like opening a vacuum-sealed coffee can or starting a car). As you say, this tends to upset people, and he gets beaten up by a younger man who knocks his teeth out.
- He's saved by someone from an underground, who shelters him, feeds him (with the peas as described above), and sets him up for a train journey to a safer community. (He also provides a chit for a dentist to fix his teeth, with the rescuer hoping it will help the old man figuratively keep his mouth shut.)
- The police (going door-to-door looking for him) show up, announcing a hefty reward of rare, vacuum-packed canned goods.
- It mentions that one of the Great Lakes is getting ready to breach the crust of a crater near the settlement to which he's headed.
- At the end, the man is on the train, and despite being warned to keep quiet, can't resist remembering something to a child passenger.

(I didn't realize that this was also filmed as an episode of *The Ray Bradbury Theater* in 1989; there's also a play version.)

Comment: The story is available in the May 1963 issue of *The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction* at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v024n05_1963-05_PDF/page/n29/mode/1up).  The bit from the question about someone trying to roll their own cigarette is on the first page.

Comment: As pointed out this was adapted for television and is easily found on youtube at the moment.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your kind attention. It’s very much appreciated.